# How to hold server side event until client side event finishes?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a MenuItem inside an UpdatePanel.  There are 2 events attached on the MenuItem:  **onClientClick** and **onClick**.

I am populating some hidden field in the onClientClick event handler.  And I am picking up the values from the hidden field inside onClick on the server side.

The problem is that both the events are firing independently.  That's why the server side code is not getting the value from the hidden field -- because it's not populated yet.

How can I postpone the server side event from firing until the client side operations are complete?

Comment: How are you calling your `onClientClick` event maybe a `return` in the call might help.

Comment: I have just mentioned the function name in the onClientClick, and in the script tag that function is defined. I am not returning any value. could you please let me know how a return value might help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute onClientClick first and then OnClick from server side, you can try something on the following line.

- Remove onClick server event from tag.
- In the javascript method specified against onClientClick, you can call the server event at the end of method. Something like __doPostBack("yourmenu", "itemclicked");

[Check out Calling ASP.NET server-side events using JavaScript](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25180/Calling-ASP-NET-server-side-events-using-JavaScrip)

Comment: Already tried that. it works but unfortunately I dont know why if I post back ma page that way, the value in the hidden field disappears.

Comment: @ManasSaha maybe the hidden field just isn't getting posted back along with the Ajax request?  Is it inside the *UpdatePanel*?